# error 403 user not logged in Postman and Laravel API

Tags: laravel, api, postman, laravel-passport, laravel-permission

I'm working on a **Laravel** API and using **Postman** to test it,

- I have a route **/api/login** that authenticates the user and return a token.

```
Route::post('login', [ApiAuthenticationController::class, 'login']);
```

The Login Method:

```
class ApiAuthenticationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Api user login
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function login(Request $request): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $token = $user->createToken('token')->accessToken;

            return response()->json([
                'token' => $token,
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Invalid username or password',
        ], 401);
    }
}
```

here's the the response:

[Login Api Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Noc96.jpg)

When I try to send a request to a route let's say: **api/v1/admin/proposals** with the Barear token that I retrieved, I get **403 forbidden** and the message USER NOT LOGGED IN

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1'], function () {
    Route::middleware(["role:admin"])->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
        Route::resource('proposals', AdminProposalController::class);
    });
});
```

[admin/proposals Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQako.jpg)

Note that the user has the role of admin, and I have **Laravel/Passport** installed.

is there any parameter to change inside postman?

Comment: I think you are missing the important middleware for your admin proposal route, try add in `Route::group(...)->middleware('auth:api')` or `Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(...);`

Comment: and the other error is due to middleware role:admin from spatie/laravel-permission , is the  user has role admin ?

Comment: tried it but it didn't work, it redirects me to the login page on **Postman**

Comment: @Win Does have a relationship with Passport? in my **config/auth.php** under **api** driver => 'passport'

Comment: api.driver => passport is correct , i think got to do with your postman header, add Accept = 'application/json' , have a look here https://www.toptal.com/laravel/passport-tutorial-auth-user-access might help you

Comment: still the error :/, the weird thing is that it worked for my colleague.

Comment: you and your colleague use the same git repo ? check your .env and compare it to your colleague's , or remove /vendor, and re-install it use "composer install"

Comment: @Win issue solved, it was a problem related to roles and permissions, I created a fresh database, seeded the roles and users, it worked
thanks mate